# react+redux reducer handling with null

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

There are some redux store of immutablejs Map. It's need to add "history" item to field.

```
    "data":{
        "country": {
            "value": "US",
            "status": "locked",
            "history": null
        },
        "city": {
            "value": "NY",
            "status": "rejected",
            "history": [
                {
                    "value": "NY",
                    "date": 1447366980,
                    "reason": "bad"
                },
                {
                    "value": "WA",
                    "date": 1447331640,
                    "reason": "badbadnotgood"
                }
            ]
        },
        "event_title": {
            "value": "test",
            "status": "new",
            "history": null
        }
    }
```

Handling this help of reducer:

```
case SET_HISTORY:
        return state
            .updateIn(['data', payload.item, 'history'],
                item => item.push(new Map({
                    reason: payload.value,
                    date: payload.date,
                    value: payload.value
                }))
            )
```

But if history is null there is error that cannot push of undefined.

What is the best practice to deal with it?

Comment: What is `updateIn` on state? Are you using any redux middleware on state?

Comment: It's immutablejs method of Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because history is `null`, and `null` doesn't have the `push` method`, it throws an error.

Add a fallback initialization `item || []`, that will assign a new array to history if `item` is `null`:

```
case SET_HISTORY:
  return state
    .updateIn(['data', payload.item, 'history'],
      // concat will return a new array, push will return the length of the array
      item => (item || []).concat(new Map(Object.entries({ // we need Object.entries because map expects an array of arrays, not an object 
        reason: payload.value,
        date: payload.date,
        value: payload.value
      })))
    )
```

**Example** 
Look at the browser's console, because the SO snippet can't show Map:

```js
const payload = {
  item: 'event_title',
  value: 5,
  date: new Date(),
  reason: 'whatever'
};

let state = Immutable.fromJS({
  "data": {
    "country": {
      "value": "US",
      "status": "locked",
      "history": null
    },
    "city": {
      "value": "NY",
      "status": "rejected",
      "history": [{
        "value": "NY",
        "date": 1447366980,
        "reason": "bad"
      }, {
        "value": "WA",
        "date": 1447331640,
        "reason": "badbadnotgood"
      }]
    },
    "event_title": {
      "value": "test",
      "status": "new",
      "history": null
    }
  }
});

state = state
  .updateIn(['data', payload.item, 'history'],
    item => (item || []).concat(new Map(Object.entries({
      reason: payload.reason,
      date: payload.date,
      value: payload.value
    }))));

console.log(state.toJS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```